# LC3 Access violation xFE00 vs x3200

Tags: assembly, lc3

I am trying to do an assignment involving strings and subroutines that will count the number of characters the user inputted and ends the program with NEWLINE. The number will be stored in R5 without counting newline. Here is my code:

```
.orig x3000
; Initialize the stack. Don't worry about what that means for now.
;Instructions (test harness)
LD R6, top_stack_addr ; DO NOT MODIFY, AND DON'T USE R6, OTHER THAN FOR BACKUP/RESTORE
LEA R1,CHAR_ARRAY
JSRR R6
LEA R0,CHAR_ARRAY
HALT

; Local data
top_stack_addr .FILL xFE00 ; DO NOT MODIFY THIS LINE OF CODE
CHAR_ARRAY .BLKW #100
.end

;=======================================================================
; Subroutine: SUB_GET_STRING_3200
; Parameter: (R1) The starting address of the character array
; Postcondition: The subroutine has prompted the user to input a string,
;                terminated by the [ENTER] key (the "sentinel"), and has
;                stored the received characters in an array of
;                characters starting at (R1). The array is NULL-
;                terminated; the sentinel character is NOT stored.
; Return Value: (R5) The number of non-sentinel characters read from the
;                    user. R1 contains the starting address of the array
;                    unchanged.
;=======================================================================
.ORIG x3200

    ;========================
    ; Subroutine Instructions
    ;========================

    SUB_GET_STRING_3200

        ST R0, BACKUP_R0_3200
        ST R1, BACKUP_R1_3200
        ST R2, BACKUP_R2_3200
        ST R3, BACKUP_R3_3200
        ST R4, BACKUP_R4_3200
        ST R6, BACKUP_R6_3200
        ST R7, BACKUP_R7_3200
        
        ; Get negative NEWLINE
        LD R2, NEWLINE_3200
        NOT R2, R2
        ADD R2, R2, #1
        AND R5, R5, x0
        
        CHAR_LOOP_3200
            GETC
            OUT
            
            STR R0, R1, #0
            
            ADD R0, R0, R2
            BRz END_CHAR_LOOP_3200
            
            ADD R1, R1, #1
            ADD R5, R5, #1
            
            BR CHAR_LOOP_3200
        END_CHAR_LOOP_3200
        
        AND R0, R0, x0
        STR R0, R1, #0

        LD R0, BACKUP_R0_3200
        LD R1, BACKUP_R1_3200
        LD R2, BACKUP_R2_3200
        LD R3, BACKUP_R3_3200
        LD R4, BACKUP_R4_3200
        LD R6, BACKUP_R6_3200
        LD R7, BACKUP_R7_3200
        RET

    ;========================
    ; Subroutine Data
    ;========================

    BACKUP_R0_3200 .BLKW #1
    BACKUP_R1_3200 .BLKW #1
    BACKUP_R2_3200 .BLKW #1
    BACKUP_R3_3200 .BLKW #1
    BACKUP_R4_3200 .BLKW #1
    BACKUP_R5_3200 .BLKW #1
    BACKUP_R6_3200 .BLKW #1
    BACKUP_R7_3200 .BLKW #1
    NEWLINE_3200 .FILL x0A

.END
```

Based of the assignment comments, I am not supposed to change xFE00. The code does not work as I get an access violation. But I have found that if I change the .FILL xFE00 to .FILL x3200, it works. I am wondering what exactly is xFE00 and how come it is causing me an access violation error and how can I make my code work with xFE00?

Comment: What is the exact error you get? Which instruction is causing the error? The `xFE00` is just a high memory address that is set aside for stack use.

Comment: Can you explain the `JSRR R6`?  I would have guessed to see `JSR SUB_GET_STRING_3200` there instead.